# How to substitute an equation in an expression in WxMaxima?

Tags: wxmaxima

I am sorry but I am quite new to Maxima.I have the following expression

[Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzAaH.jpg)

And i was trying to set maxima to rearrange it with this

[Substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWq9u.jpg)

My aim is for maxima to remove Vout and Vin completely in order to have a final expression with just VCR.

I did it "by hand" by dividing numerator and denominator by Vin^2. The result I got and that I wanted maxima to do it by himself was:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsoVI.jpg)

Comment: Good question. Since you know `VCR = Vout/Vin`, try `subst(Vout = VCR*Vin, eff_simp)` and then `ratsimp` on the result of that. Also, keep in mind it's easier for others to understand what's going on if you paste text expressions into the problem statement instead of linking images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robert, it did work! I did go around the subst() function for a while but it would always leave either Vin or Vout in the equation, depending on which it substituted. I didn't realize that ratsimp would do the trick, I thought it would just rearranje the equation but leave the Vin or Vout where it was. And sorry for the links, it was my first post here and I didn't understand why I couldn't post images.